# Django models and views functions not being called

Tags: jquery, django, json, syntax-error

I'm using the django-based implementation of http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ (a JQuery-based drag-and-drop upload library) (the django version is https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload), and have set up a small section of a larger project to use this form, which is itself installed as an application

When I navigate to the form via /upload/new (the "default" URL provided with the application), everything is fantastic -- things work exactly as they should. However, when I embed a form into a separate web page (/a/b, or whatever), hitting 'upload' presents the user with "Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character".
I've done a bit of digging and it seems no matter what I do, the functions in models.py and views.py are never called -- even though the form is constructed properly (or seemingly properly, anyway)

Since models.py and views.py aren't being called when accessing the form as part of a larger page in /a/b, how can I force them to have their functions called as they are when navigating via /upload/new?

Comment: Is the error generated by the request or by the replay? If it is at the request phase, thats why your backhand functions don't get called.

Comment: _Firebug_ is your friend man. Maybe a javascript file is missing in your page or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I used fileupload code with user authentication and was facing similar problem.
First level of debugging was done using google chrome's developer tools( CTL + SHift + I).

Network tab showed that JSON should be returned whereas HTML Error form was being returned, hence json parse error (Syntax error).

override form_invalid class to see if form is throwing error ....

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    print form
    return super(MyClass, self).form_invalid(form)
```

I then created a custom form and used form_class to pass my custom form.
I had to save the user who uploaded the file. I saved the user like this ...

```
self.object = form.save(commit=False)
self.object.user = self.request.user
self.object.save()
```

P.S. This is my first post on stackoverflow.. kindly forgive anything which goes against the   protocol of posting answers...